# How to install PyAudio 0.2.11 Fedora

Tags: python, speech-recognition, fedora, pyaudio

I want to use the SpeechRecognition library for Python, but when I try to run a program that uses the microphone, which I intend to do, I get the error

> "PyAudio 0.2.11 or later is required (found version 0.2.9)"

So I did some digging and found how to install that using apt-get. Unfortunately I run Fedora 26, so I have to use yum to install my packages, and when I looked for ways to install PyAudio using that, I was only able to find version 0.2.9.

Whenever I try to do

> pip install pyaudio

I get the following error:

> Failed building wheel for pyaudio
>     Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
>   Failed to build pyaudio
>   Installing collected packages: pyaudio
>     Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
>       Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-ZiuxD3/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-a2Iwxv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>       copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
>       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
>       gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>       gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

> Command "/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-ZiuxD3/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-a2Iwxv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZiuxD3/pyaudio/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need:

```
sudo dnf install portaudio-devel redhat-rpm-config
```

Next, you can install pyaudio.

```
pip install --user pyaudio
```

Note:

1. yum is deprecated, use dnf instead.
2. When you see compilation/building about a program, always check you have the devel dependencies like package_name-devel.
3. when installing with pip on fedora, always use --user. It will install package in your home. Else, you can create conflict with dnf packages.

Comment: The first step worked, but with the second step I got the same error.

Comment: You need this one first: redhat-rpm-config. However, portaudio-devel is necessary after. Else, you will have another similar error.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I didn't see the redhat-rpm-config the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the same error, and tried running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dnf install python-pyaudio
```

After running the above command, to verify that your pyaudio installation was successful or not, try running the code below:
`pip install pyaudio` or you can check the list of following python packages and find it there by the following command: `pip list`